# Guarantees for order of fields for data smaller than int

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have an enum class and the following three classes that I am using to model a particular (fictional) cpu.  The three POD classes model 3 different length cpu instructions, including any possible operands, and MUST be exactly 1 byte long, 2 bytes long, and 4 bytes long, respectively.

```
enum class opcode { BRK,  MOV,  LDR, .... etc...};

class op1 {
   unsigned char op;
public:
   constexpr op1(opcode o):op((unsigned char)o) { }
   constexpr opcode get_opcode() const { return (opcode)op; }
};

class op2 {
   unsigned char op;
   signed char operand;
public:
   constexpr op2(opcode o, int v):op((unsigned char)o), operand(v) { }
   constexpr opcode get_opcode() const { return (opcode)op; }
   constexpr int get_operand() const { return operand; }
};

class op3 {
   uint64_t op:8;
   int64_t operand:56;
public:
   constexpr op2(opcode o, int v):op((unsigned char)o), operand(v) { }
   constexpr opcode get_opcode() const { return (opcode)op; }
   constexpr int get_operand() const { return operand; }
};
```

I am confident that op1 and and op2 will always behave as expected, but I fear I may have some problems with op3.   While it seems to work correctly on the platform on which I'm currently developing, I'm concerned that because the order of bitfields is supposed to be implementation-defined, that the 'op' field of op3 will be in the wrong place in memory on some architectures.

I could change the data layout for op3 to the following to guarantee member order (solution 1):

```
class op3 {
   typedef struct { char bytes[7]; } operand_t;
   char op;
   operand_t operand;
public:
...
};
```

And write the constructor and get_operand member functions that access the operand field, encoding and decoding the bytes in a way controlled by the implementation of those functions.   This would also have the advantage of being able to guarantee a particular bit order within the operand, which I won't argue would be a nice to have.   However, speed of access is ultimately of more importance here, so I was thinking, perhaps, that something like this might work (solution 2):

```
class op3 {
#ifdef OPCODE_FIRST
   uint64_t op:8;
   int64_t operand:56;
public:
   constexpr op2(opcode o, int v):op((unsigned char)o), operand(v) { }
#else
   int64_t operand:56;
   uint64_t op:8;
public:
   constexpr op2(opcode o, int v):operand(v), op((unsigned char)o) { }
#endif
   constexpr opcode get_opcode() const { return (opcode)op; }
   constexpr int get_operand() const { return operand; }
};
```

Of course, I would lose a guarantee in what order the bits are in the operand field, but at least the code that accesses it will be optimal.

However, I am not sure how to define OPCODE_FIRST so that it can determined at compile time which structure arrangement to use.

So in a nutshell I'd prefer an implementation for solution1 that could reliably generate just as optimal code as accessing a bitfield, but if that is infeasible, a definition for OPCODE_FIRST in solution2.

Or, maybe there's yet another solution I haven't thought of.

Please help.   Thanks.

EDIT:

In the vein of solution 2, perhaps something like the following:

```
struct op3 {
    struct op_first_start {
        std::uint64_t op:8;
        std::int64_t operand:56;
        constexpr op_first_start(opcode o, std::int64_t v):op((int)o),operand(v) { }
    };
    struct op_first_end {
        std::int64_t operand:56;
        std::uint64_t op:8;
        constexpr op_first_end(opcode o, std::int64_t v):operand(v),op((int)o) { }
    };
#if ... ???
    op_first_start data;
#else
    op_first_end data;
#endif
public:
    constexpr op3(int o, std::int64_t v):data(o,v) { }
    constexpr opcode get_op() const { return (opcode)data.op; }
    constexpr std::int64_t get_operand() const { return data.operand; }
};
```

Although I'm still not sure what I'd need to put in the #if condition, above, to make it work as intended.

I had also been thinking that instead of the preprocessor, maybe I could use something like std::enable_if to control the type for the 'data' field in op3, but I'm not sure how that'd work, or even if it can.

Comment: If you want each class to be a specific size, why not have a single member that is an array of `char`?      `char` always has size and alignment requirement of `1`, and so does an array of them.

Comment: That could work for op2 and op1, as well as solution1 version for op3.  However,  I'm still left with not knowing how to access the operand portion with a single-expression constexpr function.

Comment: For the third option, you're using bitfields, but the sizes of fields are multiples of 8.  Which means you can use `char` or `unsigned char` instead (at least, with implementations that have 8-bit `char` types - but that's most in practice).  You might want to consider a union if you need to access parts of an array of `char` as if it has another particular type.

Comment: I know... but the advantage of using bitfields is that access is more straightforward for instructions generated.  A field that spans multiple bytes can be retrieved or written with (typically) just one or two machine instructions.   If I use an array of bytes, then it may need no less than one instruction for each byte in the array to encode or decode the operand, slowing down access time by no less than 3 times.

Comment: You either guarantee consistent layouts or optimize for speed, you don't get both, memory layouts aren't specified in the standard for a reason. As for how to manipulate the layouts at compile time, test for compiler/platform with macros.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to do with solution2.... but I'm not sure how to detect which format to use at compile time with an #if or #ifdef

Comment: If you want **guarantees**, you pretty much have to do it yourself with a raw `[unsigned] char` array.  Non-`char` types are subject to endianness of the hardware, and bitfields are probably the **worst** solution as bitfields are about as non-portable as you can get - order and endianness of bitfields are *implementation* (i.e. compiler) specified.

Comment: I am willing to use an array, but for my purposes, I absolutely *require* that the access time not have any more overhead than accessing a bitfield that happened to occupy the same range.    The first implementation I did using an array generated one instruction for each byte in the operand, even with maximum optimizations turned on, which would be 7 times slower than using a bitfield.